# How many Rare Stones does it take to fully upgrade every copy ability?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

Rare Stones can be spent at the Weapon Shop to unlock copy ability evolutions and upgrade existing copy abilities. [This guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/kirby-and-the-forgotten-land/How_to_Get_Rare_Stones) says it takes 61 Rare Stones to unlock every Copy Ability Evolution, but how many Rare Stones do you need to fully upgrade every Copy Ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Game FAQs post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/332264-kirby-and-the-forgotten-land/answers/612257-how-many-rare-stones-do-you-need-if-you-want-to-level-up-all-the-abilities-all) says you need 404 total:

> If you want to max everything out, you need to collect 404 Rare Stones total from the start of the game.
>
> 66 of these are for evolutions, and 338 are for Power Up. You can see the costs in detail here (full spoilers):
>
> [docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYBrGriAREtxMxpOt97oKFyihsmSunAFMu7VUVf1cUU](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYBrGriAREtxMxpOt97oKFyihsmSunAFMu7VUVf1cUU)